# How to test android app for various mobile variants?

Tags: android, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoa

If you are developing an iphone/iPad app is it possible to test without the device?
How about other apps like android(how to test for different variants of mobiles - say Samsung, nokia etc...).
What app do we need to test windows mobile app, blackberry app?
Please help me.

Is it possible to test an app built for iphone 5 on iphone 3? How abt the situation in the Xcode simulator or any other simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of these mobile platforms has emulators or simulators available as part of their SDK.
For example, with Android, you can create an emulator which mimics the various hardware properties of a certain phone model.

For some platforms, there are also companies which provide "device as a service", where you upload your app, and they run it and its test suite on a range of real mobile devices (e.g. [Testdroid](http://testdroid.com/) for Android, [LessPainful](https://www.lesspainful.com/) for Android and iOS, to give a couple of examples).

But overall this question is a bit too broad; Google is your friend.